# convergence of minimum points

Tags: calculus

Smooth function $\phi$ is defined on $x\ge 0$, and $\phi$ attains its minimum at $x=0$. Define functions $\phi_\varepsilon(x):=\phi(x)+\varepsilon/x$, and $\phi_\varepsilon$ attains its minimum at $x_\varepsilon$.

I want to prove the following result: (1)$x_\varepsilon\to 0$ (2)$\varepsilon/x_\varepsilon\to 0$

This result is given in a research paper without proof. I verified using $\phi(x)=x$ and it turns to be right. But I can't get the intuition behind this result, especially (2). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that (2) follows from (1) and the fact that
$$
    \phi'_\varepsilon(x_\varepsilon) = 0
    \implies
    \phi'(x_\varepsilon) - \frac{\varepsilon}{x_\varepsilon^2} = 0
    \implies \frac{\varepsilon}{x_{\varepsilon}} = x_\varepsilon \phi'(x_\varepsilon)
$$
Since $x_\varepsilon \to 0$ and $\phi$ is smooth, the right-hand side tends to $0 \cdot \phi'(0)$.